# Java SSL Client/Server random values

Tags: java, ssl

I need to get access to the SSL server/client randoms exchanged during the SSL/TLS handshake so that I can use them at a later time in the encapsulated protocol.

How do I get access to these values in Java?  I've had a look at `SSLSocket.getHandshake()` but that doesn't seem to expose the values.

Comment: This looks like a reasonable question, although the answer is likely to be "you can't do that". Why are you wanting to use those values later? That looks like a violation of layer separation and smells.

Comment: The reason is because I am implementing a tor protocol server, and because the SSL certificates are unsigned (to stop identification attacks) the inner tor protocol performs authentication of the TLS session against the signed keys in the consensus.  This is done by signing the server and client randoms.

Comment: Also, if it can't be done by JSSE then I welcome ideas on other implementations that I would be able to modify to permit this (I'd rather not modify JSSE)

Comment: Found this gist that does it albeit rather crudely:
https://gist.github.com/benmmurphy/11349193

better solutions welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no API call in the JSSE that would let you get access to it directly.

You can easily see this through `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` ("`Client Nonce`"), but that's not accessible from within the application.

You could do this via reflection on the private members, but **this is generally a bad idea** (like any use of reflection using private members on a private API). This is going to be very dependent on the version and implementation of Java you're using too.

```
    Field handshakerField = sslSocket.getClass().getDeclaredField(
            "handshaker");
    handshakerField.setAccessible(true);
    Object handShakerObj = handshakerField.get(sslSocket);
    System.out.println(handShakerObj);

    // Only start the handshake *after* you've got hold of the handshaker object,
    // otherwise it will be null.
    sslSocket.startHandshake();

    Class<?> handshakerClass = Class.forName("sun.security.ssl.Handshaker");
    Field clientRandomField = handshakerClass
            .getDeclaredField("clnt_random");
    clientRandomField.setAccessible(true);
    Object clientRandomObj = clientRandomField.get(handShakerObj);
    System.out.println(clientRandomObj);

    Field randomBytesField = clientRandomObj.getClass().getDeclaredField(
            "random_bytes");
    randomBytesField.setAccessible(true);
    byte[] randomBytesObj = (byte[])randomBytesField.get(clientRandomObj);
```

I'm not sure why your encapsulated protocol would need this. This doesn't seem like a good idea at all. It's not clear what kind of security this is meant to add. If you're really after some SSL/TLS channel token of some sorts, using the session ID would probably be better (although that's not necessarily a good idea either).

It's quite likely that most SSL/TLS stacks will not let you get hold of this in general. It's main purpose is to generate the `pre_master_secret` and ["*the pre_master_secret should be deleted from memory once the master_secret has been computed.*" (according to the TLS specification)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-8.1).

Comment: Bruno - I could kiss you! Thank you that's exactly what I'm after!

I agree it's an odd request, and I agree it's a slightly odd way of doing things but sadly this protocol is standardised and I need to implement it.  (also thanks for the pointer about PMS).

Comment: To be honest, this is all very dodgy, both the workaround via reflection, and the actual design of that authentication scheme. I'd suggest you have a word with whoever designed this to get them to reconsider what they're doing. (I've only answered because I know it's not always possible in real life, but there is a generally a strong business case for not using that sort of workaround.)

Comment: "standardised"? What kind of standard uses that?

Comment: The Tor Protocol  (see the AUTH_CHALLENGE step)

Comment: under AUTHENTICATE here: https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git?a=blob_plain;hb=HEAD;f=tor-spec.txt

Comment: For example, it is needed in TLS-DSK protocol (developed by Microsoft). You need to have client/server randoms and master secret to generate valid signatures for future SIP requests. And I agree it is very strange to require these values because signature could be computed in another more appropriate way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wondering how to extract client/server randoms from *SSLEngine* then use the following class (applicable at least for java 8):

```
package sun.security.ssl;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class SSLEngineInspector {
    private final Object transportContextObj;
    private Object handshakeContextObj;
    private byte[] clientRandom;
    private byte[] serverRandom;

    public SSLEngineInspector(SSLEngine sslEngine) {
        try {
            Field conContext = sslEngine.getClass().getDeclaredField("conContext");
            conContext.setAccessible(true);
            transportContextObj = conContext.get(sslEngine);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void captureClientHello() {
        try {
            Class<?> forName = Class.forName("sun.security.ssl.TransportContext");
            Field handshakeContext = forName.getDeclaredField("handshakeContext");
            handshakeContext.setAccessible(true);
            handshakeContextObj = handshakeContext.get(transportContextObj);

            forName = Class.forName("sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext");
            Field clientHelloRandom = forName.getDeclaredField("clientHelloRandom");
            clientHelloRandom.setAccessible(true);
            Object clientHelloRandomObj = clientHelloRandom.get(handshakeContextObj);

            forName = Class.forName("sun.security.ssl.RandomCookie");
            Field randomBytes = forName.getDeclaredField("randomBytes");
            randomBytes.setAccessible(true);
            clientRandom = (byte[]) randomBytes.get(clientHelloRandomObj);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void captureServerHello() {
        try {
            Class<?> forName = Class.forName("sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext");
            Field serverHelloRandom = forName.getDeclaredField("serverHelloRandom");
            serverHelloRandom.setAccessible(true);
            Object serverHelloRandomObj = serverHelloRandom.get(handshakeContextObj);

            forName = Class.forName("sun.security.ssl.RandomCookie");
            Field randomBytes = forName.getDeclaredField("randomBytes");
            randomBytes.setAccessible(true);
            serverRandom = (byte[]) randomBytes.get(serverHelloRandomObj);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```